If $T \in \mathscr L(V, W)$, then there exists a map $T^∗: \tau^k(W) \to \tau ^k(V ).$
$\mathscr L(V, W):=$ space of all linear transformations from $V$ to $W.$
$\tau^k(W):=$ Space of all $k-$linear transformation from $W\times W ...\times W(k-\text{times})\to \mathbb R.$
Similarly,
$\tau^k(V):=$ Space of all $k-$linear transformation from $V\times V ...\times V(k-\text{times})\to \mathbb R.$

If $T \in \mathscr L(V, W)$, then there exists a map $T^∗: \tau^k(W)
 \to \tau ^k(V ).$

My attempt:-
For the case of $k=1$. I know there exists such function. Defined like $T^*(g)(v)=g(T(v)), \forall g\in \tau^1(W).$
For the case of $k>1.$
$T^*(g)(v_1,v_2,...,v_k)=g(T(v_1),T(v_2),...,T(v_k)), \forall g\in \tau^k(W).$
Am I correct?

There exists a map $T^*:\tau^k(W)\to \tau^i(V)$ such that $\ldots$?

@user469053 no other condition given

we just need to prove the existence  of such map.

Then just use the zero map. You don't need any $T$.

they might mean the nontrivial one.

They can't, because there might not be a non-trivial one.

I believe you have not included the entire problem, because otherwise the "If $T\in\mathcal{L}(V,W)$" is totally unnecessary, but the map they're looking for is called $T^$. There must be more to the problem explaining that they want some relationship between $T$ and $T^$.

https://web.math.ucsb.edu/~jhateley/project/tensor.pdf I was proving the proposition 5

I suspect this is a typo in their notes. Just taking a quick look, those notes have many typos. I also looked at their reference (Serge Lang's Algebra, ch 16), and I didn't see this problem.
If $T=0$, then your example is the zero operator. If $V$ or $W$ is the zero vector space, then only the zero map exists between $\tau^k(W)$ and $\tau^k(V)$.
In any case, yes, your operator $T^*$ is exactly the correct $k$-fold tensor product of the adjoint of $T$, which is what I believe the problem is asking for.

I think the author of the notes meant to add some additional conditions relating $T^*$ to $T$, and part of the importance of the problem is establishing a relationship between transformations/adjoints/tensor powers.

i didn't understand Lang. he was talking about modules.
